# Does java utilize the GPU for painting

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

Does paint, or paintComponent utilize the GPU for drawing images on the screen?

I have a program that is loading images on a JPanel at 60fps, and I wonder if that is too much for a game I'm making

Comment: [Prototype](http://sscce.org/) and [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513).

Comment: I would suggest that would come down the underlying libraries it uses.  For example under Windows I believe they use DirectX and OpenGL on linux (could be wrong there)

Comment: I would doubt that these specifics would be part of the JVM specification.

Comment: 60 FPS is the baseline most games try to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be.  Best way to know how to proceed would be to do a test and load a bunch of fake images, and makes sure you don't drop frames.  Even if you use the GPU it might not be fast enough on your device, so recommend testing regardless.

Comment: It most definitely doesn't use the CPU, because when repainting at 1000FPS, the CPU usage doesn't go past 2-3% usage.